# python: urllib.request.urlopen() HTTP Error 308 Permanent redirect

Tags: python, urllib

i was just trying to read a file from the internet..
then an error came..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Sapphire\Programming\download_file.py", line 46, in <module>
    download(arg[1])
  File "E:\Sapphire\Programming\download_file.py", line 19, in download
    file_info = req.urlopen("http://proget.whirlpool.repl.co/{}/{}.txt".format(arch, name))
  File "E:\Programming\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "E:\Programming\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "E:\Programming\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "E:\Programming\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "E:\Programming\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "E:\Programming\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 308: Permanent Redirect
```

the line that brought the error (line 20):

```py
file_info = req.urlopen("http://proget.whirlpool.repl.co/{}/{}.txt".format(arch, name))
```

(the link that it should use is correct..)
any ideas how it came?

```
SPECS:
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Python: Python 3.8.10
Arch: x86 (32-bit)
```

Comment: have you tried https?

Comment: Python versions before 3.11 did not handle 308 redirects [[ref](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84501)], so one option is to just upgrade to Python 3.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Http is outdated, so most sites would redirect to https.

So use

```
file_info = req.urlopen("https://proget.whirlpool.repl.co/{}/{}.txt".format(arch, name))
```

Comment: I am using BeautifulSoup for URL "https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/St.-Louis_MO"    After some processing I form a new URL "https://www.realtor.com//realestateandhomes-detail/9717-Sappington-Rd_Saint-Louis_MO_63128_M73336-90474?from=srp-list-card". This URL is working fine when I access it from browser. But, this line in Python is failing "webpage1 = urlopen(req1).read()".  This is what I am giving for headers "req1 = Request(newURL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})" - Please let me know what am I missing

Comment: i used `URL = 'https://www.realtor.com//realestateandhomes-detail/9717-Sappington-Rd_Saint-Louis_MO_63128_M73336-90474?from=srp-list-card'
website = requests.get(URL)
results = BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'html.parser')
print(results)` and it shows me the site without a problem, but please make a new question with more code to debug

Comment: Thanks for responding. When I run my script it prompts me to enter URL. I enter "https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/St.-Louis_MO". And then I dynamically form another URL "https://www.realtor.com//realestateandhomes-detail/9717-Sappington-Rd_Saint-Louis_MO_63128_M73336-90474?from=srp-list-card" . For this running this line of code results in 308 "webpage1 = urlopen(req1).read()"   - Stackoverflow has suggested multiple times to use the existing thread and not create a duplicate. Sorry man - Would appreciate if you can answer here. Thanks

Comment: i need to see your code, so make a new question with code and check again my code copy it and make a new python file, my code works just fine, but without eeing yours nobody can help you

Comment: Have posted my question. Can you please have a look and let me know your thoughts? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76734960/how-to-scrape-all-pages-from-realtor-website-that-has-pagination-using-python